# Need explanation about probability

Tags: probability

I wanted to learn about probability, I have here a sample question that i want to base as my starting point. This was given as our homework but was never discussed in class on how to solve it.

> Charlston Wilbur is a fisherman with customers in Connecticut and
>   Rhode Island. In Connecticut he sells to 2 supermarkets, 1 restaurant,
>   3 grocery stores and 2 fish markets; in Rhode Island to 2
>   supermarkets, 1 restaurant, 2 grocery stores and 3 fish markets. They
>   all send him new orders at the beginning of the week. Early Monday
>   morning he gets the first order from Connecticut and the first from
>   Rhode Island. What's the likelihood that at least one is from a
>   supermarket?

```
Given:

 Connecticut
2 supermarkets
1 restaurant
3 grocery stores
2 fish markets

  Rhode Island
2 supermarkets
1 restaurant
2 grocery stores
3 fish markets
```

I am confused on where to start on this, a little explanation on how to start solving it will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: What is the probability that both orders are not from supermarkets? How does this relate to the probability that at least one is from a supermarket?

Edit: It appears my hint wasn't so helpful, so here is a more detailed answer.

Note that 1/4 businesses in Rhode Island are supermarkets, and 1/4 businesses in Conneticut are supermarkets.

So 3/4 businesses in both states are not supermarket.

For there to be at least one supermarket in the order from both places, then it has to be the case that *both* first orders are *not* from supermarkets. In an equation:

$P(\text{at least one supermarket})=1-P(\text{both not supermarkets})$

$P(\text{both not supermarkets})=P(\text{Conneticut not supermarket})\times P(\text{RI not supermarket})\\
=(3/4)\times(3/4)=9/16$

So $P(\text{at least one supermarket})=1-(9/16)=7/16$

Comment: my guess would be..i added them all by category. 4 supermarkets, 2 restaurants,5 grocery stores,
5 fishmarkets. which means  4+2+5+5=16. 4 out of 16 possibilities is supposed to be a supermarket. answer would be 4/16 or rounded off to 1/4. I am really new to this please bear with me.

Comment: Not quite. What you have done there is found the probability that one random choice from either Connecticut or Rhode Island is a supermarket. You have two orders, and you know where they are from. What's the probability that the first Rhode Island order is a supermarket? And what about Connecticut? For there two be at least one order from a supermarket, either one or both of these orders are from supermarkets. Keep going!

Comment: Both rhode island and connecticut has a probability of 2/8 basing on number of supermarkets each. does it mean 2/8 is the answer? but it just ends up to 1/4 when rounded off.

Comment: Nope. There are two events, and you need to take into account both of them. Let's just call them order 1 and order 2, the state names are too long to type. For at least 1 supermarket we can have the following: order 1 = supermarket and order 2=supermarket; order 1=not supermarket and order 2=supermarket; order 1=supermarket and order 2=not supermarket. To calculate these probabilities, you can multiply the probabilities of the individual events, because the events are independent. Then add them together.

Comment: This is where my hint came in. Can you see how there are so many events to calculate? What you can instead is $P(\text{at least 1 supermarket order})=1-P(\text{no supermarket order})$, with $P(\text{no supermarket order})=P(\text{not a supermarket from Conneticut})\times P(\text{not a supermarket from Rhode Island})$

Comment: i am now having problems on what values would i put basing on your formula. This is my first time encountering this, i am really sorry if i am slow regarding this matter.

Comment: Don't worry about it. So long as you put in the effort to understand it, I don't mind explaining. I'll elaborate in the answer. Let me know exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: thanks for this. i will be using this as my guide. marking this as an answer.